# find xml-nodes by tag with wildcard

Tags: python-3.x, xml, xpath

I am trying to find any nodes in a xml whos tags start with a certain pattern.

```
<data> 
<general>
    <va value="400" /> <!--looking for this "v-tag"-->
    <vb value="42"  /> <!-- and this one-->
    <y value="43" />
</general>
<special>
    <va value="100" />  
</special>
</data>
```

I cannot put together the xpath expression. Something like this

```
xyz = lxml.etree.parse( ... )
vees = xyz.xpath("general/[tag='v*']")
```

I would like to have vees beeing

```
vees
Out[64]: [<Element va at 0x....>, <Element vb at 0x...>]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing:

```
vees = xyz.xpath("general/[tag='v*']")
```

to

```
doc.xpath('//general//*[starts-with(name(),"v")]')
```

and see if it works.

Comment: Yes this works. Thanks. Does anyone know a concise and comprehensive documentation of the xpath-language without 90% of it's content beeing browser- or stylesheet-related stuff?

Comment: @Axel I'm afraid that's not the kind of question you can get an answer for on SO. There's a lot of stuff about xpath and xml, including a few books - just do some searching and you'll probably find something to suit your needs. In the interim, if we are done, please don't forget to accept the answer.